# How do resolve macro from preview mode inside Kentico CMS

Tags: macros, kentico

I need to show a setting key from a Text Editable widget, it works fine in preview mode. But inside CMS it just show macro code.
Is there any way to run macro in preview mode both in CMS and live site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro code will only display in Edit mode otherwise you'd have no way to editing or knowing there is a macro there.  Once the system is running in preview or live site mode, it will render without issue (assuming you have a valid macro).

Comment: got it. thank you. but I think we still have another way to edit them by view source

Comment: Yes, you can edit them by clicking the Source button but you cannot add macros that way as they will be automatically converted to encoded HTML by the WYHISYG editor.  It's a touchy setup and in most cases, we don't educate users on how to enter macros on those fields because there are too many issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to test or debug a macro, you can go to System > macros > Console or Benchmark